# Не удается создать таблицу.

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE 'sessions'(
'session_id' VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
'last_active' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
'contents' TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('session_id')
INDEX ('last_active')
)ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Вот что пишет:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near ''sessions'( 'session_id'
> VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL, 'last_active'
> INT UNSIGNED NOT ' at line 1

Где я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки исправьте на **`** - accent. И запятую добавьте между `PRIMARY KEY` и `INDEX`

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions`( `session_id` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL, `last_active` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `contents` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`), INDEX (`last_active`) )ENGINE = MYISAM
```